# Hacer clic en un botón y esconder un div en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo se puede seleccionar un div concreto para hacerlo desaparecer al presionar un botón?

He intentado con este código y no me sale, desaparecen todos los divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("div").hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<button id="hide" type="submit">Siguiente </button>
```

Comment: `$('div')` selecciona todo elemento HTML que sea de tipo div, tienes que usar algúna propieda de HTML para ser más específico, como un id o una clase. `$('#idDiv')` ó `$('.idClass')`

Comment: Mamen!  te sugiero realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio, también es importante leas [ask] que te brinda información para realizar tu pregutna y esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.  Recuerda que para agregar más info a tu pregunta, usa el botón "editar".

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo por medio de los id`s  de los elementos por ejemplo :

```js
    $(function(){
        $("#BotonParaEsconder").click(function(){
            $("#DivAEsconder").hide();
        });
    });
```

```css
.panel_error {
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="BotonParaEsconder" value="Esconder div" />
<br/><br/><br/>
    <div class="panel_error"  id="DivAEsconder">

    escondeme :D
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso te pasa por que al hacer esto `$("div").hide();` estas seleccionando y escondiendo absolutamente todos los `<div>`:

SELECCIONAR UN DIV POR MEDIO DE SU ID

```
$("#div").hide();
```

SELECCIONAR UN DIV POR MEDIO DE SU CLASE

```
$(".div").hide();
```

Así puedes seleccionar un elemento específico ya sea por su `id` o por su `class`

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
$('#div').css("display","none");
```

Lo que hacemos es modificar el atributo css del div y lo ocultamos, si deseas mostrarlo nuevamente usas la misma linea pero cambias el "none" por "inherit" o cualquier otro modo de vista que necesites.

Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. mira por favor [answer]. En general se pide que las respuestas no sean solo una linea de codigo, si no que tengan algun tipo de explicacion. Gracias por el aporte!

Answer (score -1):

también puedes ocultar el objeto con efectos con Jquery con:

```
$(div).fadeOut();
$(div).slideUp()
```

Puedes ocultar/Mostrar con:

```
$(div).fadeToggle();
$(div).slideToggle();
```

Answer (score -1):

Cuando usas `$('div')` estas diciendo todos los elemento tipo `<div`
cuando usas `$('.div')` estas buscando toda las clases div `<div class="div"` por ultimo cunado usas `$('$div')` estas buscando los id  `<div id="div"` 
en caso de haber muchos id buscara el ultimo

la nueva version de JQuery tiene una opcion de [`.toggle();`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) una variacion del ejemplo de [Xique](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/107635/28035) , a diferencia de este al hacer click si esta oculto lo muestra y si no lo oculta digamos que automaticamente hace el **`if`**

```js
    $(function(){
        $("#BotonParaEsconder").click(function(){
        $( ".panel_error" ).toggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
.panel_error {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.70);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="BotonParaEsconder" type="submit">Siguiente </button>
<div class="panel_error">por favor ocultame</div>
```